# How to add url variable setup for html page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have onepage.html file and How to setup a url variable in data-bind. is there any js file to add this. Billing address html file and related billingadres.js is there. but there is no js file for onepage.html. how to add data-bind for this file.

```
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('errors') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
<div class="ddd_opc_clear"></div>
<div id="ddd_opc_top" class="ddd_opc_universal_wrapper ddd_opc_two_column_wrapper">
    <div class="ddd_opc_button" style="color: #fff;border-color: #ab1d29;background: #ab1d29;border-radius: 0;max-width: 280px; float: left;
"><a style="color: #fff;"  >Back to Shopping Cart</a></div>
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('login-button') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
    <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('sidebar') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!--/ko-->
</div>
<div class="ddd_opc_clear"></div>
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('steps') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!--/ko-->
```